# Mysql Automatically duplicate data

Tags: mysql, database-design, phpmyadmin

Well it's pretty complex to explain but what I have is a database with a table of addresses. What I want to do is duplicate that table in another database so I can access the same data.

So basically  its like  I want Database A Table A to be the same data as Database B Table A

Comment: the term to search is `database replication`.

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html

Comment: I dont have console access

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DatabaseB.TableA`;
CREATE TABLE `DatabaseB.TableA` SELECT * FROM `DatabaseA.TableA`;
```

Notice that this won’t recreate the primary keys or indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If the two databases are accessible at the same time (ie on the same server and any user has access to both) you can create a new identical table using [`CREATE TABLE LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) and [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html)

```
CREATE TABLE DatabaseB.TableA LIKE DatabaseA.TableA;
INSERT INTO DatabaseB.TableA SELECT * FROM DatabaseA.TableA;
```